# Disable the conversion from "" to “” when typing Chinese

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, input-source, text-input

Every time I type in a quote mark (`"`), the "smart" Chinese input method would automatically convert it to `“` or `”` for me. But compilers and interpreters don't know what `“”` mean, they can only recognize `"`.

How can I disable this conversion?

Comment: @Panda I've tried TextEdit(GUI) and vim(CLI). Both of them have done such conversion.

Answer (score 1):

In most Cocoa-based applications, you can disable this by unchecking Edit > Substitutions > Smart Quotes.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't seem to work for Chinese input

Answer (score 0):

In TextEdit, try invoking caps lock before typing quotes.